# How to get date in this format Sun May 17 2015 09:31:49

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I am getting Date in Calender object from one of the client API in this format `"2015-05-17T09:31:49"` but i want it to be displayed in `"Sun May 17 2015 09:31:49"`. I tried below code but it is giving me output in this format `Sun May 17 00:00:00 IST 2015`

```
SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyy-MM-dd"); 
String input = "2015-05-17T09:31:49";
Date t = ft.parse(input); 
System.out.println(t.toString());
```

Someone please guide me how to do this.

Comment: Yes, so you need to use another SimpleDateFormat with the pattern you want to *format* as...

Comment: SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyy-MM-dd"); 
    String input = "2015-05-17T09:31:49";
    Date t = ft.parse(input); 
    SimpleDateFormat newsdf= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    System.out.println(newsdf.parse(t).toString);

Comment: see my answer. @user3592257

Answer (score 0):

Check this can help you:

```
SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyy-mmm-dd HH:mm:ss"); 

    String input = "2015-05-17 09:31:49";
    Date t = ft.parse(input); 
    System.out.println(t.toString());
```

Comment: Sat Jan 17 09:31:49 IST 2015

Answer (score 0):

```
java.text.DateFormat outputFormat =new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss");
java.text.DateFormat outputFormat1 =new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
System.out.println(outputFormat.format(outputFormat1.parse("2015-05-17T09:31:49")));//Sun May 17 2015 09:31:49
```